# Validating current URL after clicking a context menu item

Tags: python, win32com, win32gui, pywinauto

I am writing a python script where I right-click a file, click on a context menu item. On clicking it opens a webpage. I have to validate the url of the webpage. How do I shift my control from OS to the browser and get Current URL.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you call requests.get(url) and check the response code. Another option is to call request.head(url)

```
>>> import requests
>>> url1 = 'http://example.com'
>>> url2 = 'http://sdsdsdsdsdss.com'
>>> r = requests.head(url1)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r = requests.head(url2, timeout=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 77, in head
    return request('head', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 387, in send
    raise Timeout(e)
requests.exceptions.Timeout: (<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7f4e77635950>, 'Connection to sdsdsdsdsdss.com timed out. (connect timeout=5)')
>>>
```

You need to handle the exception. Details about requests module: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

And if you really need to open the web browser, you can use this library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: Hi, thnx for your help. requests.head(url1) doesn't work for me as I cant pass url as attribute manually. The links provided were very helpful though.Here I am trying to open a link by right clicking on a file, click on a context menu item. This opens a link in browser. I have to verify whether it opens correct link. How do I shift my control from Windows application to the browser to get URL. Do I need to use selenium driver?

Comment: I didn't play with selenium, but it might be helpful for you.